# Android Two DatePickers - limit max date on second

Tags: android, date, events, datepicker

In my android fragment, i have 2 date pickers and when the date is set on the first one, I want to limit the maximum date on the second one to be +1 year ahead.

Here is some code showing how I implement the pickers:

```
 startDateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            startDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int y, int m, int d) {
                    //Set start date
                    startDate = calToDateString(y, m, d);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), startDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            // init datepicker
            startDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), startDateListener,
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            startDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
    endDateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            endDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int y, int m, int d) {
                    queryEndDate = calToDateString(y, m, d);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), queryEndDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            endDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), endDateListener,
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            // *** Can only set max date here initially - startDate has not been set ***
            Date endMax = getTodaysDate();
            endDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(endMax.getTime());
            endDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, when the maximum date for the end date picker is set - the start date from the first date picker has not been entered. How can I set the max date of the second date picker, when the first (start) date is entered? I think I need an event listener for the startDate variable, but I am not sure on how to implement it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DatePickerDialog dpd=new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
int dayOfMonth) {
Date myMaxDate;
    endDatePicker.setMaxDate(myMaxDate);

}
```

Comment: I know how to set the maxDate. That wasn't what I asked. I actually have the code to do it shown in my question.

Comment: im sorry, i didnt get it well... Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: So what you are saying is to set it in the date set method of the first date picker. I didn't actually think of that. I was trying to over-engineer it, making it too complicated. I think I'm sleepy as well ;)

Comment: Thats right :) BTW whenever you think you are making things too complicated you probably are. :)